# Compare List to Enum Where Contains Any

Tags: c#, linq, enum

I have a List that I want to compare to an `Enum`.

If `a.Value` is found in the `Enum` we return `true`.

I feel that I should be able to make this a single line, but have struggled.

```cs
private bool IsFound(IEnumerable<SomeAttribute> attributes)
{
    foreach (AttributesInMethod option in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AttributesInMethod)))
    {
        if (attributes.Any(a => option.GetDisplayNameENUM().Contains(a.Value)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest a two lines of code solution instead of one. :)

Let me show you first the solution then the explanation.

### Solution

```cs
private static readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<string>> enumValues = new Lazy<IEnumerable<string>>(() => Enum.GetValues(typeof(AttributesInMethod)).Cast<AttributesInMethod>().Select(option => option.GetDisplayNameENUM()));

private bool IsFound(IEnumerable<SomeAttribute> attributes) => attributes.Select(att => att.Value).Any(enumValues.Value.Contains);
```

### Explanation

#### Two methods instead of one

- You have two kinds of data

  - A fairly static data, which could be changed only with code change

    - The mapped values of the enumeration
  - An absolutely dynamic data, which could change by each and every method call

    - The `IsFound` input parameter

You don't need to calculate each and every time the derived data from the enumeration. It should be calculated once and stored for long term.

#### Usage of Lazy

*"It should be calculated once and stored for long term."* > That's where the `Lazy<T>` type comes into play.

All you have to do is to provide a factory method (how to compute the derived data) and then the calculated information should be stored in a long-living variable. `Lazy<T>` gives us thread-safety so there is a guarantee that it will be calculated only once.

#### How to derive the data

```cs
Enum.GetValues(typeof(AttributesInMethod))
  .Cast<AttributesInMethod>()
  .Select(option => option.GetDisplayNameENUM())
```

`GetValues` returns an `Array` so you have to call `Cast<T>` to be able to use Linq operator on it.

#### Composing functions

For each input data check the existence of it in a predefined collection.

- For each input data: `attributes.Select(att => att.Value)`
- check the existence of it: `.Any(... .Contains)`
- in a predefined collection: `enumValues.Value`

All you have to do to compose them to create a new higher level function.